# Android data recovery of lost photos

Tags: data-recovery

Last night, we were looking at photos I took and this morning, a large number of them disappeared. My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S20. All the photos from April to now are just gone; sadly there is no backup on any cloud.

I am comfortable enough to use adb, so if someone could talk me through the steps, it would be much appreciated. I don't know how or why they all got deleted. I don't want to use any of these applications like Dr. Fone Wondershare or Tenorshare because they seem kind of sketchy to me.

Comment: did you perform any software update or something? what pictures you're talking about? is their storage space freed or still occupied? if the files were deleted they are gone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to recover deleted files without root on Android 12?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246215/is-it-possible-to-recover-deleted-files-without-root-on-android-12)

Comment: Are you using Google Photos or other cloud sync services?